# doPost skipping response.sendRedirect()

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm sending a user to a servlet `Login` where the doPost method is:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("hit login doPost");
    response.sendRedirect("account.jsp");
}
```

It prints "hit login doPost" when I debug, but skips right over the second line where I'm wanting to redirect. Here is my form (this is on `index.jsp` page):

```
<form action="Login" method="post">
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: isnt the account.jsp page opened?

Comment: No, `index.jsp` is where the form is.

Comment: index.jsp has the form and when you submit it calls the servlet and response.sendRedirect() takes you to account.jsp

Comment: That is correct. I'll edit the question to be a little more clear.

Comment: look strange actually, can you try replace `button` by `input`!

Comment: @MuhammadHewedy OP says he is getting **hit login doPost** so this means servlet is called from the form.So I think replacing button with input is not required

Comment: @MuhammadHewedy I agree with JqueryLearner, but I still tried it and no luck. It's definitely submitting the form, just not executing the line I want.

Comment: If you're interested, please see my answer for what it was. Just needed to re-build and restart I guess.

Comment: Yes guys you are right, but this is very strange!... Well I just tried it on my own and it works from me... It is clearly some thing goes wrong on your machine/app!

Comment: I've now changed the output message slightly and tested several times by stopping, removing, re-building, and adding project back to server and it doesn't take any changes unless all of these are done together. Very weird.

Answer (score 1):

With a combination of stopping tomcat, removing the project from the local tomcat server in eclipse, right clicking on the project name and 'Build Project', and re-running on the server it finally worked. I was simply restarting the server, and I guess it wasn't rebuilding with my changes automatically.

So, to clarify I took these steps to ensure my dynamic web project took servlet changes:

1. Stop local Tomcat server
2. Remove the project under "Servers" tab in eclipse
3. Right click on the project in Package or Project Explorer
4. `Build Project`
5. Right click on server, and Run As Server again

For some reason, it wouldn't take changes unless I've done every single step above.

Comment: I agree with you, and this is was about my last comment! good luck